# js ставить HTML рядом с элементом

Tags: javascript, dom

Здравствуйте,
Можно вставить html во внутрь элемента
elem.innerHTMl = html;

А как его вставить рядом? (before/after без разницы)
Не создавая допольнительного wrapper

Большое спаибо

Comment: [append/prepend, before/after, replaceWith](https://learn.javascript.ru/multi-insert#append-prepend-before-after-replacewith)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал пример с использованием [этой функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), хотя меня немного смущает её статус `Working Draft`:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');


function pasteAfterEnd() {
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>Абзац 100</p>');
}

function pasteBefore() {
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Абзац 0</p>');
}

function pasteAfter() {
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>Абзац 3</p>');
}
```

```css
#elem {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">
  <p>Абзац 1</p>
  <p>Абзац 2</p>
</div>

<button onclick="pasteAfterEnd()">Вставить рядом</button>

<button onclick="pasteBefore()">Вставить перед</button>

<button onclick="pasteAfter()">Вставить после</button>
```

Comment: здесь ты его вставляешь _внутрь_ elem, а в вопросе надо _рядом_

Comment: добавил функцию "вставить рядом" :)

Comment: @Grundy, `'beforebegin'` и `'afterend'`, а метод тот же.

Comment: Дай я тебя расцелую !!!)))) Спасибо большое, именно то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem'), // поиск нужного элемента
 p = document.createElement('p');    // создание "вставляемого" элемента
p.innerHTML = '0';                          // наполнение его контентом

elem.parentElement.insertBefore(p,elem);    // добавление контента через родителя
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p id="elem">3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
```